# jshint and variable names out of my control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, jshint

I'm handling an oauth response from twitter in an angular page that reads the parameter like this:

```
var oauthToken = $location.search().oauth_token;
```

Jshint will complain because

```
line 13  col 0   Identifier 'oauth_token' is not in camel case.
```

Alternatively I can write it as

```
 var oauthToken = $location.search()['oauth_token'];
```

But then jshint will complain

```
 line 13  col 40  ['oauth_token'] is better written in dot notation.
```

Is there a recommended way to handle these without using a //jshint ignore:line comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var OAUTH_TOKEN = 'oauth_token';
var oauthToken = $location.search()[OAUTH_TOKEN];
```

Ofc choose a more appropriate name for the variables